# how can i make thumb images without cropping in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to make thumb image with the size 200*151. I don't want to crop image. The thumb should be look like orignal image. 
What's coding to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at MGImageUtilities from Matt Gemmell - [MGImageUtilities](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/05/mgimageutilities)

It's a couple categories on UIImage that provide methods for resizing images. You simply pass in a CGSize (for instance `CGSize thumbnailSize = CGSizeMake(200.0f, 151.0f);`) and it will return a resized image.

Answer (score 0):

Hello just resize the frame of the imageView e.g.

```
   imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,151);
```

then crop the images of full size.. for cropping you can see the blog[blog](http://www.hive05.com/2008/11/crop-an-image-using-the-iphone-sdk/)